# Any way to access pyomo variable

Tags: pyomo

I am new to pyomo. Here is the line on my code which may be having some issue:

```
model.delivery = Var(model.days, model.del_types, within=Binary, bounds=(0, 1), initialize=1)
```

How can I access model.delivery. When I am calling it from my console it is giving:

```
<pyomo.core.base.var.IndexedVar at 0x18bf876b8c8>
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking to access? The variable’s value after you have solved your problem?

Comment: No, During the process. I am getting infeasible solution so, want to debug.

Comment: So you would like to check the variable’s value while the solver solves the problem?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: I am afraid I do not know if and how this would be possible (perhaps solver callbacks can do that, but I’m not sure).